# Changing QGIS system SVG path with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I am trying to change the SVG path with Python but I couldn't find any document which explains how to do this.
This is what I want to do
I Added SVG symbols to my plugin in a specific folder. 
When the plugin initiates I want to check SVG paths in system/ option.
if the path does not exist then I want to add it.

[image]

I tried the following code in python console but It does Nothing

```
 QSettings().setValue(u'/qgis/system/Qgis/system/svg_paths', u'C:\1234m')
```

it gives no error but It does nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Tested in QGIS 3.2 python console under Ubuntu 18.04 :**

To find the settings you need, you can use

```
settings = QSettings().allKeys()
```

This will create a list of all available Settings (it can help to find the settings you need)

```
for setting in settings:
    if 'svg' in setting:
        print(setting)
```

will print `'svg/searchPathsForSVG'`

Then you can use this strings to play with the setting. The `searchPathsForSVG` is stored as a list of paths so you first need to retrieve the current list (eventually loop on it to check what you want) and if everything is good append your new path.

```
my_new_path = '/toto/titi/tata'
svg_paths = QSettings().value('svg/searchPathsForSVG')
if my_new_path in svg_paths:
    pass
else:
    svg_paths.append(my_new_path)
    QSettings().setValue('svg/searchPathsForSVG', svg_paths)
```